# Load the date separated by '/' with the Datetime datatype in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, types, date-format

```
INSERT INTO PUZ_DATE_FORMAT 
    SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'d', 'it-IT') AS ItalianDate
```

I get this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My table contains only a single column of `datetime` datatype, and the format statement which I've written will give the output like 15/12/2017.

But when I try to insert a row into the table, it won't allow me to do so. It allows only dd-mm-yyyy format - not dd/mm/yyyy. Why?

Comment: Why are you attempting to convert at all? GETDATE() returns a datetime, which you can insert without effort. Datetime doesn't have a format, a format is applied when a datetime value is shown on screen or otherwise printed.

Comment: To add on to what @HoneyBadger said, datetimes are stored in the database in a binary structure. The display format of those values is entirely controlled by the presentation application.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do is insert a string value to a Datetime field. In doing so, SQL Server try to cast the string to a datetime during the insert. If your string is in the Universal format (yyyy-MM-dd) it can successfully parse it without any issue. Else the string has to be in the datetime format as Server's culture.

I guess your Server's culture is en-US which has the date time format as "MM/dd/yyyy". With regarding to your date (15/12/2017) server thinks 15 is the month, 12 is the day and so on. Which is obviously falling.

If you tried this before 12th of the month, It can successfully cast, But to an incorrect value.

Further, you are not doing the right thing by, casting a Datetime to a string and then try to insert in to Datetime field. Try to store the raw Datetime in database and format accordingly when displaying in UIs.

Cheers,